# Host multiple Symfony projects on the same domain

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I have one domain and i need to host many symfony 3 projects in differents folder. For example :

www.domain.com/project1
www.domain.com/project2
...

My current nginx conf is :

```
server {
    server_name domain.fr www.domain.fr;
    root /var/proximiteclient/www/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        #internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
      return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain_access.log;

    listen 80; # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.fr/fullchain.pem; # manag$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.fr/privkey.pem; # man$
    ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_session_timeout 1440m; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE$



    #Redirect non-https traffic to https
    if ($scheme != "https") {
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

Sorry, i can't put in text mode it didn't work :(

Thansk very much !

Comment: You missed the nginx config part

Comment: Added ! Butt sorry it refused my conf :(

Comment: i have added my nginx conf !

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a pseudo-apache setup where you have "sites-available" that are auto-loaded into your nginx config.

For example:

```
//nginx.conf
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Then create `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and create a "site config" for each of the domains. This will keep them cleanly separated.

```
//etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dev.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    ssl off;
    server_name dev.example.com;
    root /path/to/example/web;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name dev.example.com;
    return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

And a second site for good measure..

```
//etc/nginx/sites-enabled/staging.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    ssl off;
    server_name staging.example.com;
    root /path/to/example2/web;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name staging.example.com;
    return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Surely this wont work for a single domain setup, like the OP requires, without changing ports

Comment: Of course it will, my example names were misleading, so I've updated them, but you could just as easily do `{subdomain}.example.com` for each of the `server_name` configs (I've done this on several projects with great success).

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to do this is to duplicate your server blocks and specify a different listening port and root path.

project 1 url: http://www.domain.fr

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.fr www.domain.fr;
  root /var/project1/www/web;
  ...
}
```

project 2 url: http://www.domain.fr:801

```
server {
  listen 801;
  server_name domain.fr www.domain.fr;
  root /var/project2/www/web;
  ...
}
```